# How activate cmd.exe window's "Scroll mode" via a Win-32 API function?

Tags: windows, winapi

In the cmd.exe window there is a status called "Scroll mode". At [this site](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/keyboard-ninja-scrolling-the-windows-command-prompt-with-only-the-keyboard/) there is a description of how to activate it; via keyboard: Alt-Space, then Edit, then scroLl; or via mouse: right-click on the title bar, then select Edit and Scroll.

My question is simple: what Win-32 API function is used to activate this status?

I reviewed the [SetConsoleMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686033(v=vs.85).aspx) function, but it does not manage this mode (nor anyone of the rest of [console functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx)). I searched the web looking for "cmd.exe scroll mode", but no one of the multiple results refers to *this* mode...

Comment: It's not controlled by a public API. This is a user setting. You can trigger it by modifying the registry, but you shouldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging and tests, it *"seems"* that this behaviour is not exposed by any public API function. While someone find a non obvious way (or still better an obvious one), this workaround can be used

```c
#define _WIN32_WINNT   0x0500
#include <windows.h>

#define SC_SCROLL 0xFFF3

int main(void) {
    HWND hWnd;

    // Search current console
    if (!(
        hWnd = GetConsoleWindow()
    )) return 1;

    // Set scroll mode
    if ( 
        SendMessage(
            hWnd
            , WM_SYSCOMMAND
            , (WPARAM) SC_SCROLL
            , (LPARAM) NULL 
        ) != 0
    ) return 2;

    // Done
    return 0;
}
```

**edited** to adapt to comments

To disable the scroll, we only need a <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> key press

```c
#define _WIN32_WINNT   0x0500
#include <windows.h>

#define KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN 0

int main(void) {
    INPUT ip;

    // Keyboard input structure initialize
    ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    ip.ki.wScan = 0;
    ip.ki.time = 0;
    ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

    // Control key down
    ip.ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;
    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN;
    SendInput( 1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT) );

    // C key down
    ip.ki.wVk = 'C';
    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN;
    SendInput( 1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT) );

    // C key up
    ip.ki.wVk = 'C';
    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    SendInput( 1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT) );

    // Control key up
    ip.ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;
    ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    SendInput( 1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT) );

    // Done
    return 0;
}
```

This code sends a <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, but you can not indicate the target of the keypress. To avoid problems from focus loss it is probably better to send the <kbd>Esc</kbd> directly to the window

```c
#define _WIN32_WINNT   0x0500
#include <windows.h>

int main(void) {
    int KEY = VK_ESCAPE;
    unsigned int lParamKeyDown = 0;
    unsigned int lParamKeyUp = 0;

    HWND hWnd;

    // Search current console
    if (!(
        hWnd = GetConsoleWindow()
    )) return 1;

    // Configure lParam for key down event
    lParamKeyDown |= 1;
    lParamKeyDown |= 1 << 24;
    lParamKeyDown |= MapVirtualKey(KEY, 0) << 16;

    // Configure lParam for key up event
    lParamKeyUp |= 1 << 30;
    lParamKeyUp |= 1 << 31;
    lParamKeyUp |= MapVirtualKey(KEY, 0) << 16;

    // Send the key
    SendMessage( hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, KEY, lParamKeyDown );
    SendMessage( hWnd, WM_KEYUP, KEY, lParamKeyUp );

    // Done
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Three points about this solution: first of all, **IT WORKS! ^_^**    **2.** IMHO this is not a workaround, but the standard way to activate this mode. Several of the `WM_SYSCOMMAND` messages that start with `SC_` controls some scrolling aspect of the window, so this is just another status of same type. However, ...

Comment: **3.** This `SC_SCROLL 0xFFF3` value is **NOT** documented anywhere! It don't appear in [this reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360(v=vs.85).aspx) nor in other similar ones, and is neither included in the *.h files of VisualStudio nor in the *.inc files of MASM. A Google search of "WM_SYSCOMMAND SC_SCROLL" don't give _a single exact match_!!! Where you got this value from? I need also the value to turn this mode off...

Comment: @Aacini, `SC_SCROLL` (the name) is just a guess. The value was retrieved and confirmed via subclassing, api monitoring and, of course, debugging. I see it as a workaround because it does not ask for a *scroll mode*, it only sends to the window the same message that is generated selecting the `Scroll` option in the window system menu. Unfortunatelly, I have not found a reliable way to check if it is enabled but it should be easy to disable it (see updated answer)

Comment: @Aacini, I was not very happy with the previous posted code to disable the scroll hence I have included another option.

Comment: I invite you to review my [SendMessage.exe](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7583) auxiliary program, that I developed using the information you provided here. **`:)`**

Comment: There is a simpler way to know these values: `Mark=FFF2, Copy=FFF0, Paste=FFF1, SelectAll=FFF5, Scroll=FFF3, Find=FFF4`. See [this new post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=50434#p50434)...

Comment: @Aacini, Was it *simpler* to write the tool in assembly? You are used to this and find it natural to do it this way. I'm used to the disassembler. And the menu ID message was my last option / workaround when I didn't found a safe way to request the change to the scroll mode.

Comment: I am talking about this code, that list all these numbers: `hMenu = GetSystemMenu(GetConsoleWindow(),FALSE); for ( i=0; i<GetMenuItemCount(hMenu); i++ ) printf("%X\n", GetMenuItemID(hMenu,i));`. After that, is easy to test each number and know its function. IMHO this method is much simpler than use a disassembler...

Comment: @Aacini, The dissasembler was used to follow how the mode was enabled, to locate the functions that handle the start and end of it (by the way i saw that I needed to send the virtual key codes of the `Esc` key, not only the `0x1a` character, to disable the mode) to see if they are directly callable. To find the menu item you don't even need code. The `inspect.exe` tool included in the SDK directly gives you the menu information.

Comment: @Aacini, sorry º~º, `0x1b`